# Is Google Charts limited?

Tags: google-visualization

I'm looking to use the [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/) for generating charts using JavaScript and I read that the old Google Chart Api was limited for the amount of queries per day per users ([read post here](http://googlecode.blogspot.fr/2008/03/lifting-limit-on-calls-to-google-chart.html)).

So I was wondering if this limitation was applied to the Google Charts (using JavaScript) or only for the images, and/or if there is an other limitation (free for non commercial, etc).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically, the Interactive Charts are not limited, since with most charts, the workload is entirely handled on the client side, so there is no workload for Google to limit.  For the few charts that do access Google's servers (geocoding requests from GeoCharts/GeoMaps are the only ones that come to mind), there is not currently a limit.

The API is free to use for both commercial and non-commercial purposes.

Read the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/chart/terms) for details.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. That's what I thought but I couldn't find any proof of that.

Comment: Geocoding requests are covered under the [Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) and is limited by 4.2 and 10.1.1 (i). Current limits are shown [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usagelimits) (currently 25,000 map loads/day). What constitutes a map load is listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage_mapload) but doesn't specifically include geocoding.

Comment: My understanding is that the geocoding is not limited, as long as you use it with a Google product (which the Visualization API certainly is).  If anyone knows differently, please correct me.

Comment: From [geocharts documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart?csw=1#Data_Policy): *"Locations are geocoded by Google Maps. Any data that does not require geocoding is not sent to any server. Please see the [Google Maps Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms) for more information on their data policy."*

Comment: As above, I can't see any specific restriction on geocoding amounts from the terms.